# Storing boost::function object with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function

What I'm trying to achieve is creating a struct which stores any kind of method. I can later call struct_object.run() to run the method I've stored.

This method can return any kind of value and, most importantly, use any amount of parameters; however, I can't get around the "any amount of parameters" issue.

Mind you, the following code doesn't even build, mostly because I have no clue on what the correct syntax would be like.

**ApplicationPair.h**

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct ApplicationPair
{
    ApplicationPair(boost::function<T()> func, Args... arguments )
    {
        _func = func(Args::arguments...);
    }

    ApplicationPair() = delete;

    void run(); 
    boost::function<T(Args...)> _func;
};

#endif
```

And then, what I'd like to do is the following:

**main.cpp**

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void ApplicationPair<T,Args...>::run()
{
    this->_func;
}

//TEST

int counter = 0;

void HelloWorld()
{
    std::cout << "HelloWorld\n";
}

void printNumber(int i)
{
    std::cout << "Print: " << i << std::endl;
}

void increaseCounter(int x)
{
   counter+=x;
}

int main()
{
    ApplicationPair<void> p1(HelloWorld);
    ApplicationPair<void> p2(printNumber, 5);
    ApplicationPair<void> p3(increaseCounter, 10);
    p1.run();
    p2.run();
    p3.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, the methods I want to store shouldn't be modified or adapted in any way: I want to be able to create any kind of method without caring about the fact that struct ApplicationPair will store it for its own personal use.

All I get with this though is a long string of errors like:

> error: in declaration ‘typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral::value), boost::function&>::type boost::function::operator=(Functor)’

Comment: Unrelated: If you are using C++11 or later, you can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of `boost::function`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah I'm just using boost::function because that's what I'm asked to use at work.

Comment: how are you planning to call the functions when they can have any number of paramters? And how do you want to use the returned values? `this->_func;` does nothing, you have to actually call the function

Comment: the parameters are already passed on construction? In that case you only need to store functions that take no parameters and bind the parameters

Comment: Is there a particular need for the name `run`? If you changed it to `operator()`, you can use `boost::function<void()>` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below line:

```
ApplicationPair<void> p2(printNumber, 5);
```

you have to specify all types in template arguments list, not only `void` as return type, `int` as argument of constructor should also be added. Now `args...` is empty. What is wrong. The same with `p3`.

Make constructor as templated method taking paramters pack as argument for your callable:

```
template<class F, class ... Args>
ApplicationPair(F&& func, Args... arguments )
{
    _func = boost::bind(std::forward<F>(func),arguments...);
}
```

then `args...` can be deduced when invoking constructor. Your class template takes only a type for return value.

```
template<class Ret>
struct ApplicationPair {
    template<class F, class ... Args>
    ApplicationPair(F&& func, Args... arguments )
    {
        _func = boost::bind(std::forward<F>(func),arguments...);
    }
    ApplicationPair() = delete;
    void run() {
        this->_func();
    }
    boost::function<Ret()> _func;
};
```

In constructor `boost::bind` is used to bind passed parameters to callable. You don't store parameters anywhere, therefore they must be bound in functor created by `boost::bind`.

Uses:

```
ApplicationPair<void> p1(HelloWorld);
ApplicationPair<void> p2(printNumber, 5);
ApplicationPair<void> p3(increaseCounter, 10);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Xnkd6g)

---

Don't use `boost::bind`, it is limited to handle only max 9 arguments.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I'll have to study the code a bit to understand how everything works exactly (like the fact you're using std::forward, which I've unfortunately never used before) but now I finally have a correctly working code.THANK YOU!

Comment: `std::forward` maintains the value category of the parameter

Answer (score 1):

You've already gotten an answer but here's a C++17 alternative capable of deducing the return value type as well as the argument types of the function using a deduction guide, making both the return type and argument types part of the `ApplicationPair<>` type. I've chosen to store the arguments separately in a `std::tuple<Args...>`.

`boost::function` can be replaced with `std::function` in this example in case you later decide to go with the standard:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct ApplicationPair {
    ApplicationPair() = delete;

    ApplicationPair(Func func, Args... args) : 
        _func(func),
        // store the arguments for later use
        arguments(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {}

    decltype(auto) run() {        // I'd rename this: decltype(auto) operator()()
        return std::apply(_func, arguments);
    }

    boost::function<T(Args...)> _func;
    std::tuple<Args...> arguments;
};

// deduction guide
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
ApplicationPair(Func, Args...) -> 
    ApplicationPair<std::invoke_result_t<Func, Args...>, Args...>;
```

```
int counter = 0;

void HelloWorld()
{
    std::cout << "HelloWorld\n";
}

void printNumber(int i)
{
    std::cout << "Print: " << i << std::endl;
}

int increaseCounter(int x) // changed return type for demo
{
   counter+=x;
   return counter;
}

int main()
{
    // full deduction using the deduction guide
    ApplicationPair p1(HelloWorld);
    ApplicationPair p2(printNumber, 5);
    ApplicationPair p3(increaseCounter, 10);
    p1.run();
    p2.run();
    std::cout << p3.run() << '\n';
    std::cout << p3.run() << '\n';
}
```